# scale_fill_identity plot legend with full values, not only values present in data

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

My data:

```
structure(list(day = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", 
"08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "01", "02", 
"03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", 
"05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", 
"08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
"19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
"30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
"10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", 
"21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "01", 
"02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", 
"04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
"15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
"26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
"06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
"17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
"28", "29", "30", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
"09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
"20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", 
"31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", 
"11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", 
"22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "01", "02", 
"03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
"25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"), month = c("01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
"01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
"02", "02", "02", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
"03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
"03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
"03", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
"04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "05", "05", 
"05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", 
"05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", 
"05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
"06", "06", "06", "06", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
"07", "07", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
"08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
"08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
"09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
"09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
"09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
"10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
"11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
"12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
"12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
"12"), tmean = c(6.6, 5.5, 10.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), percentile = c(63, 48, 95, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), pct_cut = structure(c(5L, 4L, 6L, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), levels = c("#2166ac", 
"#67a9cf", "#d1e5f0", "#f7f7f7", "#fddbc7", "#ef8a62", "#b2182b"
), class = "factor")), class = c("rowwise_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -366L), groups = structure(list(
    day = c("01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
    "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
    "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
    "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
    "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
    "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
    "29", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", 
    "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
    "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", 
    "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
    "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
    "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
    "29", "30", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", 
    "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", 
    "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", 
    "29", "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", 
    "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
    "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
    "28", "29", "30", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", 
    "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", 
    "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
    "28", "29", "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", 
    "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
    "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
    "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
    "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
    "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", 
    "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
    "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
    "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "01", "02", "03", "04", 
    "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
    "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
    "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "01", "02", "03", "04", 
    "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", 
    "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", 
    "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31"), month = c("01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", "01", 
    "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
    "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", 
    "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "02", "03", 
    "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
    "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
    "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", "03", 
    "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
    "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
    "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", "04", 
    "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", 
    "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", 
    "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", "05", 
    "05", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
    "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
    "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", "06", 
    "06", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
    "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
    "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", "07", 
    "07", "07", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
    "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
    "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", "08", 
    "08", "08", "08", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
    "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
    "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", "09", 
    "09", "09", "09", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
    "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
    "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", 
    "10", "10", "10", "10", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
    "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
    "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", "11", 
    "11", "11", "11", "11", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
    "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
    "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", "12", 
    "12", "12", "12", "12", "12"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 
        2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
        15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
        26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 
        37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
        48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 
        59L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 
        70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 
        81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 
        92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 98L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 
        103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 
        112L, 113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 119L, 120L, 
        121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 
        130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
        139L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 
        148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
        157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 
        166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 
        175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 
        184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 
        193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 
        202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 
        211L, 212L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 
        220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 
        229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 
        238L, 239L, 240L, 241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 
        247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 
        256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 263L, 264L, 
        265L, 266L, 267L, 268L, 269L, 270L, 271L, 272L, 273L, 
        274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 
        283L, 284L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 
        292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 
        301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 307L, 308L, 309L, 
        310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L, 315L, 316L, 317L, 318L, 
        319L, 320L, 321L, 322L, 323L, 324L, 325L, 326L, 327L, 
        328L, 329L, 330L, 331L, 332L, 333L, 334L, 335L, 336L, 
        337L, 338L, 339L, 340L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 345L, 
        346L, 347L, 348L, 349L, 350L, 351L, 352L, 353L, 354L, 
        355L, 356L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 361L, 362L, 363L, 
        364L, 365L, 366L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -366L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")))
```

My code:

```
ggplot2::ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = day, y = month, fill = pct_cut)) +
    ggplot2::geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.1) +
    ggplot2::geom_text(aes(label = percentile), vjust = 1, fontface = "bold", na.rm = TRUE) +
    ggplot2::scale_y_discrete(
      limits = rev, # to put labels in reverse order (Jan -> Dec instead of Dec -> Jan)
      labels = rev(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))
    ) +
    ggplot2::scale_fill_identity(guide = "legend", labels = c(0, 5, 20, 40, 60, 80, 95, 100)) +
    ggthemes::theme_hc(base_size = 15) +
    ggplot2::labs(
      x = "", y = "", title = paste0("Temperature in Madrid - Retiro ", 2024),
      subtitle = paste0("Daily mean temperature vs. empirical distribution (", 1920, "-", 2024, ")"),
      color = NULL, fill = NULL
    ) +
    ggplot2::theme(
      plot.title = ggplot2::element_text(hjust = 1, face = "bold", family = "sans", size = 35),
      plot.subtitle = ggplot2::element_text(hjust = 1, size = 25),
      legend.spacing.x = ggplot2::unit(0, "cm"),
      legend.key.size = unit(3, "line"),
      legend.title = ggplot2::element_text(family = "sans")
    ) +
    guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 1, label.position = "bottom", label.hjust = 0,
                               title = "Percentile", title.position = "top"))
```

With my data and my code I get the following legend with only 3 colors:

[image]

I know I get that legend because my data in column `pct_cut` only has those colors. However, despite my data, I always want to plot the full legend with colors `c("#2166ac", "#67a9cf", "#d1e5f0", "#f7f7f7", "#fddbc7", "#ef8a62", "#b2182b")` as in screenshot below.

`pct_cut`is calculated as `dplyr::mutate(pct_cut = cut(percentile, breaks = c(-0.1, 5, 20, 40, 60, 80, 95, 100), labels = c("#2166ac", "#67a9cf", "#d1e5f0", "#f7f7f7", "#fddbc7", "#ef8a62", "#b2182b")))`

[image]

How can I achieve it the simplest way possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the `limits=` for the scale. But overall I would suggest to switch to `scale_fill_stepsn` and map `percentile` directly on the `fill` aes like so:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = day, y = month, fill = percentile)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.1) +
  geom_text(aes(label = percentile), vjust = 1, fontface = "bold", na.rm = TRUE) +
  scale_y_discrete(
    limits = rev, # to put labels in reverse order (Jan -> Dec instead of Dec -> Jan)
    labels = rev(month.abb)
  ) +
  scale_fill_stepsn(
    guide = guide_colorsteps(
      show.limits = TRUE,
      label.position = "bottom", label.hjust = 0,
      title = "Percentile", title.position = "top",
      barwidth = unit(10, "cm")
    ),
    breaks = c(0, 5, 20, 40, 60, 80, 95, 100),
    colors = c("#2166ac", "#67a9cf", "#d1e5f0", "#f7f7f7", "#fddbc7", "#ef8a62", "#b2182b"),
    limits = c(0, 100),
    na.value = "transparent"
  ) +
  ggthemes::theme_hc(base_size = 15) +
  labs(
    x = "", y = "",
    title = paste0("Temperature in Madrid - Retiro ", 2024),
    subtitle = paste0("Daily mean temperature vs. empirical distribution (", 1920, "-", 2024, ")"),
    color = NULL, fill = NULL
  ) +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 1, face = "bold", family = "sans", size = 10),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 1, size = 8),
    legend.spacing.x = unit(0, "cm"),
    legend.key.size = unit(3, "line"),
    legend.title = element_text(family = "sans")
  )
```

[image]